# How do i map one-to-one relationship in Windows Phone 7 Localdb?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mapping, one-to-one, localdb

I have two table in my Windows Phone 7 localdb and i would like to map a one-to-one relationship between them. Suppose to have a these class:

```
[Table]
public class HouseOwner
{
  [Column]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Column]
  public string Surname { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class Home
{
  [Column]
  public string Address { get; set; }

  [Column]
  public string EnergyClass { get; set; }
}
```

How can i do that?
I found a lot of example about how to map one-to-many relationship but none about this case.

Comment: Found any answer to this?